# How to sort HashMap keys using a data structure, then print the key with it's associated value?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, hashmap

Let me start off by saying I am not looking to use TreeMap or any built-in sorting class.

I currently have a long list of product codes and their associated names in a CSV file. I have created a parser which stores a few values from the CSV file:

1. Stores product codes into an ArrayList named productCodesList.
2. Stores product names into an ArrayList named productNamesList.
3. A HashMap called productMapper which maps the product codes to their respective product names.

My goal is to sort the productCodesList in order using a few algorithms which I will implement. I've already implemented the ArrayList quicksort, which successfully returns the keys in ascending order. Now, I'm somewhat confused as to how to refer back to the HashMap using these now-sorted keys to display their associated values side by side in order. Any tips on how to move forward?

An example at what I'm doing ---------

```
Key: "3" Value: "Oranges"
Key: "1" Value: "Bananas"
Key: "7" Value: "Peaches"
Key: "15" Value: "Tomatoes"

***After the key values are sorted using quicksort, print properly sorted HashMap keys with their values***

Key: "1" Value: "Bananas"
Key: "3" Value: "Oranges"
Key: "7" Value: "Peaches"
Key: "15" Value: "Tomatoes"
```

Comment: `sortedKeys.stream().forEach(key -> String.format("Key: %s, Value: %s", key, originalMap.get(key)));` --- I would strongly recommend to not re-write standard sorting algorithms.

Comment: Unfortunately I am required to per this assignment. There are over 60,000 products and codes in the CSV file I have to sort through using various data structures, then I have to compare which one's are more efficient.